# Is there a way to mount Google account folders automatically at startup?

Tags: online-accounts

I have two Google accounts (one personal, one for school) connected to Gnome in Ubuntu 19.04. Is there a way to make these folders automatically mount when I turn on my computer? It's not really that big of a deal having to manually mount them each time I want to use them after startup, but sometimes it takes a long time for the contents of the folders to load, so I was wondering if there is a way to make this process automatic so they're ready to use when I need them. Any help/information is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This link for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS but no reason not to believe it will work with 19.04 https://linuxconfig.org/google-drive-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open "online accounts", "google", insert mail and password. Your file manager will mount the email addresses so you can directly, manually copy files. Mounting is done automatically on boot but can be a bit slow: it can only be done after the network is up and connecting will always take a little bit of time too.

There is software in the repositories that is called [open drive](https://snapcraft.io/odrive-unofficial) and it will automatically sync for you. This will automate copying files to google drive and from google drive.

edit: one thing I can not check is doing this with more than one mail address. I assume it is just a repeat setting this up :-)

Comment: This might be what I'll have to do. I don't want to have to re-install `snapd` because snaps always seem to be crazy slow or broken, but if I can't find any other option I may not have a choice.

Comment: Not any more. snaps had a bug with loading fonts that got fixed.